# An asymptotic numeric problem.

Tags: numerical-methods, asymptotics

Given a large enough integer $N$ is there always a $c\in(0,1)$ such that $$(N+ N^{1-c}){c\ln(e N)}>\ln( N+( N)^{1-c})(N+2 N^c)$$ holds?

What is this $c$ explicitly (at least a close approximation is fine)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; for any $c \in (0,1)$ the left hand side is $cN\ln(N) + o(N\ln(N))$, and the right hand side is $N\ln(N) + o(N\ln(N))$, so the right hand side will dominate for large enough $N$.

Comment: may I also ask what about $$\frac{2(e(N)^{c})^{1/4}}{1+c\log N}>\frac{ N}{\log(e( N)^{c})}?$$

Comment: Also no, since the right hand side is $\frac{N}{o(N)}$ and the left hand side is $o(N^{c/4})$.

Comment: one last query in $F(N,t)=\frac2{eN^{1/t}}-\frac1{(t-1)log N)}-1-0.001$ given $N$ is there a $t>1$ such that $F(N,t)>0$ always holds? What is maximum such $t$?

Comment: No again; $N^{1/t}$ grows faster than $\log N$, so for any $t > 1$, $F(N,t)$ will be negative for large enough $N$.